# Fitted h1 inside parent

Tags: html, css

I wanna fit `h1`, like here: [Everything ok example](http://jsfiddle.net/dhW28/)

Code:

```
.container {
    padding: 2em 3em;
}

h1 {
    text-align:center;
    line-height:4em;
    color:white;
    background: black;
    /*padding: 2em 3em;*/
    margin: -2em -3em 0 -3em;
}
```

But then I insert

```
margin: 0 auto;
max-width:10em;
```

It doesn't work...

[Last example](http://jsfiddle.net/9brSS/1/)

Comment: Didn't got your question

Comment: To look like the first example. H1 now also have margins(0 auto), I want to see H1 without white spaces.

Answer (score 0):

As i understand  you want to center text, and fill space

```
.container {
    padding: 2em 3em;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}

h1 {
    text-align:center;
    line-height:4em;
    color:white;
    background: black;
    margin: -2em -3em 0 -3em;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9brSS/3/)

Comment: If he wants to do that, than what was wrong with his first example?

Comment: Everything Ok with my first example, but without max-width:10em;

Answer (score 0):

Here we have 2 solutions

First is only remove "max-width:10em;"

And second is

```
.container {
padding: 2em 3em;
margin: 0 auto;
max-width:10em;
min-width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You defined a width of `10em` on `.container`. If you want to center `.container` with `margin: 0 auto;` it needs to have a fixed width. If you want it wider, then increase `max-width:10em;` to your desired size.

So your end result will be something like:

```
.container { margin: 0 auto; max-width: 30em; /*whatever width you want*/ }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the `max-width` to `min-width` and change the value to `100%`.